# Object does not support this 'property' or 'method'

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8

I know that there are already some asked questions with the same error message, but they are not the same and I tried some of the suggested solutions and it did not work.
The thing is I call the following method in SharePoint site and it works perfectly when creating a new item but it fails with the stated error when I edit the item. 
I have no clue what is going on.

My method is like this:

```
function PopulateModuleCode() {

  "use strict";
  var organisationvalue = $("select[title='Organisation Required Field'] option: selected ").text();

    var taskvalue = $("input[title = 'Task Required Field']").val();
    var training = $("input:radio[name$='ctl00$RadioButtons']:checked + label").text();
    var extractorganistionvalue = organisationvalue.split(/\s*\-\s*/g);
    var calculation = extractorganistionvalue[0] + '-' + taskvalue + '-' + training.charAt(0);

    if ($("input[title='Module code Required Field']").val(calculation)) {

    }
    if ($("input[title='Module code']").val(calculation)) {

    }

    var rest = calculation.length - 20;

    if (calculation.length > 20) {
      $("input[title='Module code']").css("color", "red");
      $("input[title='Module code Required Field']").css("color", "red");
      $("input[title='Module code']").val("Valid length (maximum 20 characters) is exceeded with " + rest + " characters");
      $("input[title='Module code Required Field']").val("Valid length (maximum 20 characters) is exceeded with " + rest + " characters");
    } else {
      $("input[title='Module code']").css("color", "#001965");
      $("input[title='Module code Required Field']").css("color", "#001965");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What line causes the error?

Comment: "use strict"; but when I comment it out it gives the same error with the next line

Comment: In your code, have you splitted the line defining `organisationvalue` in the same way it is splitted in the post? If you have, the string needs to be fixed to one-liner, strings can't be spread onto multiple lines. This causes a syntax error, and the function won't be defined.

Comment: No, I see what you mean...it is the stackoverflow editor that splitted it up into two lines

Comment: javascript doesn't like line breaks in strings (must be an epidemic)

Comment: As I wrote just before it is the stackoverflow editor, I just corrected the line

Comment: Remove the new-line between `"`s, and test if the code works. Arbitararily pointed error line comes from IE8, it just always can't point correct lines, especially when the script is embedded in the html file. Also, jQuery version must be 1.* when using IE<9.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which new line? please bear up with my stupidity

Comment: Never mind the new-line, you edited your comment about having it to opposite = ). How about the jQuery version?

Comment: I'm using 1.10.2.min.js

Comment: That should work. Because of the poor error line pointing of IE8, you've to to try find the correct line by commenting out everything within the function, then remove the commenting line by line starting from the beginning. At some point the error occurs. If it occurs even when everything is commented out, the error source is not in that function. In that case I can only wish you good luck when debugging with IE8 ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is been fixed by changing the $ alias with jQuery. 
As I stated in the question, I call the method from a sharepoint site and it works with new items without any issue, but it fails in edit item...googling and trying different suggestion resulted in the fix.